# unable to store the reference of the non serializable object

Tags: java, serialization

Hi team recently I have started with the I/O package and I have faced one issue As shown in the below code I have a class Identity having a reference of the non-serialize class Address. I want to store the address object along with the identity class but while reading the object, I am unable to get back the Address Object and it's throwing null pointer exception in my main class Below I have shown all the code related to my problem please do the needful.

```
Address class--

package com.io.practice;
public class Address {

    String state;
    String country;

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}


Identity Class--

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.io.practice.Address;

public class Identity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    transient Address address;
    int panCardId;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getPanCardId() {
        return panCardId;
    }

    public void setPanCardId(int panCardId) {
        this.panCardId = panCardId;
    }

    public void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) throws IOException {
        os.defaultWriteObject();
        os.writeObject(address);

    }

    public void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        is.defaultReadObject();
        this.address=(Address) is.readObject();
    }

}

GraphTest main class--

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import com.io.practice.Address;

public class GraphTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Identity id = new Identity();
    Address add = new Address();
    add.setCountry("Austrialia");
    add.setState("Sidney");
    id.setPanCardId(560100);
    id.setAddress(add);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/cgi.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    objectOut.writeObject(id);
    objectOut.flush();
    objectOut.close();
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("D:/cgi.ser");
    ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    Identity identity = (Identity) objectIn.readObject();
    System.out.println(identity.getPanCardId());
    System.out.println(identity.getAddress().getCountry());

}

}
```

`System.out.println (identity.getAddress().getCountry());` over this line am getting null pointer.please co rrect the code if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: transient Address address; transient attributes are not persisted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store Address object of Identity you have to remove `transient` and make Address `Serializable` so that you don't get a `NotSerializableException` when serializing the Identity object.